# Htaccess url redirect and masking, multiple query strings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-masking

I have tried almost every redirect and htaccess masking solution to this problem on stackoverflow,

I am able to redirect urls i.e:

A. http://www.autotraderuae.com/news/man-up-/2681

REDIRECTS TO:

B. http://www.autotraderuae.com/news/news_detail/man-up-/?id=2681

But I'd like to the url in the browser to still show (A) and not (B) without changing the php structure ofcourse.

Code currently being used is:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^news/([a-z0-9-.?]+)/([0-9]+)? news/news_detail/$1/?id=$2 [L,QSA,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

The page redirects because you've included the `R` flag at the end, [which indicates redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html). You need to remove it and only keep the `L` and `QSA` flags.